# Oracle stored procedure not working PLS-00306

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

i have this questions i am trying to solve and find below what i have solved so far. although the stored procedure haveno error but calling it i get this error :

> ERROR at line 2: ORA-06550: line 2, column 3: PLS-00306: wrong
>   number or types of arguments in call to 'PUB_JOB_COUNT' ORA-06550:
>   line 2, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Requirement:

> Create a stored PL/SQL procedure object in the database. The procedure
>   should insert the publisher’s name, city, telephone number and the
>   number (count) of jobs he/she requested in the table PublisherDetails
>   for each Publisher who requested less than three print jobs otherwise
>   the procedure should display on the screen the publisher name followed
>   by job number, job start date and job completion date for each job
>   he/she requested. Screen output (hint: use the concatenation operator
>   ‘||’) should be in the following format:

Please someone help me out please?

Publisher Name: Addison-Wesley

```
       JobNo    Start Date       Completion Date
         12       17-JAN-14         25-JAN-14
         14       28-FEB-14         01-APR-14
```

> Finally, a NO-DATA-FOUND exception should be catered for in the
>   EXCEPTION section and a message displayed on the screen (hint: use
>   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line procedure provided by Oracle) informing the user
>   if such an error arises. Note that in order for DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line
>   to work in SQL*Plus, you should set SERVEROUTPUT on first. You should
>   check if the procedure executes properly by invoking the procedure and
>   checking the content of the PublisherDetails table. Do the following:
>   a)    Create a script file with the necessary code to create the table
>   PublisherDetails and the PL/SQL procedure in the database; b) Create a
>   second script file with the following: •   An SQL statement that clears
>   the content of the table PublisherDetails; •  A PL/SQL anonymous block
>   statement to invoke (execute) the PL/SQL procedure; •  A SELECT
>   statement to select all the records in PublisherDetails table.

my tables

```
publisher(publisherName, publisherCity, phoneNo)
             pk

printJob(JobNo, startDate, complitionDate, publisherName)
           pk                                fk(publisher)

publisherdetails(publisherName, publisherCity, phoneNo, JobNo)          
                     pk
```

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUB_JOB_COUNT (
       JOBNO IN NUMBER
) AS
       PUBLISHERNAME  PRINTJOB.PUBLISHERNAME%TYPE;
       NOTFOUND EXCEPTION;
       CURSOR PUBCURSOR IS
       SELECT PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERNAME,
              PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERCITY,
              PUBLISHER.PHONENO,
              PRINTJOB.STARTDATE,
              PRINTJOB.COMPLETIONDATE,
              SUM(JOBNO) AS NUMOFJOBS
         FROM PUBLISHER
        INNER JOIN PRINTJOB ON PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERNAME = PRINTJOB.PUBLISHERNAME
        GROUP BY PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERNAME,
                 PUBLISHER.PUBLISHERCITY,
                 PUBLISHER.PHONENO,
                 PRINTJOB.STARTDATE,
                 PRINTJOB.COMPLETIONDATE;
       PUBREC         PUBCURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
       OPEN PUBCURSOR;
       FOR PRINTJOB IN PUBCURSOR LOOP
              PUBLISHERNAME := PRINTJOB.PUBLISHERNAME;
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Publisher Name : ' || PRINTJOB.PUBLISHERNAME);
              LOOP
                     FETCH PUBCURSOR INTO PUBREC;
                     EXIT WHEN PUBCURSOR%NOTFOUND;
                     IF PUBREC.NUMOFJOBS <= 3 THEN INSERT INTO PUBLISHERDETAILS VALUES (
                            PUBREC.PUBLISHERNAME,
                            PUBREC.PUBLISHERCITY,
                            PUBREC.PHONENO,
                            PUBREC.NUMOFJOBS
                     );
                     ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PUBREC.NUMOFJOBS
                                               || ' '
                                               || PUBREC.STARTDATE
                                               || ' '
                                               || PUBREC.COMPLETIONDATE);
                     END IF;
              END LOOP;
       END LOOP;
       CLOSE PUBCURSOR;
       COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
       WHEN NOTFOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record Not Found');
END;
```

Gleaned from comments below, the code being used to execute the procedure:

```
BEGIN
 pub_Job_Count;
End;
```

Comment: you showed everything except the most important part - your code used to call PUB_JOB_COUNT. That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: Hi, the code for calling my stored procedure is : BEGIN
  pub_Job_Count;
     End;

Comment: That's your problem, you need to send it a number, the jobNo per your procedure definition

Answer (score 0):

Your program is expecting an input, a number.

But when you call it, you're not providing said number.

So, the database gets upset and issues this:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUB_JOB_COUNT'
```

To fix it,

```
BEGIN
 pub_Job_Count(1); -- your number is added here, either explicitley or via a variable you add in a DECLARE
END;
/
```

A basic example

```
clear screen

create or replace procedure so_missing_inputs (x in integer, y in date) is
begin
 dbms_output.put_line('X is: ' || x);
 dbms_output.put_line('Y is: ' || to_char(y, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
end;
/

set serveroutput on

declare
 a integer := 2;
 b date := sysdate;

begin
-- so_missing_inputs(); -- missing 2 inputes
-- so_missing_inputs(1); -- missing 1 inputs
-- so_missing_inputs(sysdate, 2); -- right number of inputs, but not right data types
 so_missing_inputs(x => a, y => b); -- let's be explicit about inputs vs coutning on right order
end;
/
```

If I run this -

[image]

If you were to uncomment one of the previous lines, you'd see the PLS-00306 creep back in.

One final note, on DBMS_OUTPUT. It's a good way to see what things are happening while 'debugging' your code, but it's not a good way to communicate things outside the PL/SQL program.

Comment: note this is quite clearly a homework assignment...and i chose to answer your most pressing question - why you couldn't run your program. You'll need to do your own code review to see if it meets your professor's requirements.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks alot but i have edited the code to "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUB_JOB_COUNT AS" as i dont want to input a number to get my result. but when i run it i get  the error " ORA-06511: PL/SQL : cursor already open ......ORA-06512: at  DB LINE 5 AND LINE 13

Comment: that's a new question...otherwise you're asking us to fix the entirety of your procedure, you need to present a clear question/issue.